# Ambiguity with column reference

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I try to run a simple code as follows:

```
Create Table weather (
    city        varchar(80),
    temp_lo     int,
    temp_hi     int,
    prcp        real,
    date        date
);
Insert Into weather Values ('A', -5, 40, 25, '2018-01-10');
Insert Into weather Values ('B', 5, 45, 15, '2018-02-10');

Create Table cities (
    city        varchar(80),
    location    point
);
Insert Into cities Values ('A', '(12,10)');
Insert Into cities Values ('B', '(6,4)');
Insert Into cities Values ('C', '(18,13)');

Select * From cities, weather Where city = 'A'
```

But what I get is

> ERROR: column reference "city" is ambiguous.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you I'd model things slightly differently.

To normalise things a little, we'll start with the cities table and make a few changes:

```
create table cities (
    city_id     integer primary key,
    city_name   varchar(100), 
    location    point
);
```

Note that I've used an integer to denote the ID and Primary Key of the table, and stored the name of the city separately. This gives you a nice easy to maintain lookup table. By using an integer as the primary key, we'll also use less space in the weather table when we're storing data.

```
Create Table weather (
    city_id     integer,
    temp_lo     int,
    temp_hi     int,
    prcp        real,
    record_date  date
);
```

Note that I'm storing the id of the city rather than the name. Also, I've renamed `date` as it's not a good idea to name columns after [SQL reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Ensure that we use IDs in the test data:

```
Insert Into weather Values (1, -5, 40, 25, '2018-01-10');
Insert Into weather Values (2, 5, 45, 15, '2018-02-10');

Insert Into cities Values (1,'A', '(12,10)');
Insert Into cities Values (2,'B', '(6,4)');
Insert Into cities Values (3,'C', '(18,13)');
```

Your old query:

```
Select * From cities, weather Where city = 'A'
```

The name was ambiguous because both tables have a `city` column, and the database engine doesn't know which `city` you mean (it doesn't automatically know if it needs to use cities.city or weather.city). The query also performs a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), as you have not joined the tables together.

Using the changes I have made above, you'd require something like:

```
Select * 
From cities, weather 
Where cities.city_id = weather.city_id
and city_name = 'A';
```

or, using newer join syntax:

```
Select * 
From cities
join weather on cities.city_id = weather.city_id
Where city_name = 'A';
```

The two queries are functionally equivalent - these days most people prefer the 2nd query, as it can prevent mistakes (eg: forgetting to actually join in the `where` clause).

Answer (score 5):

Both tables `cities` and `weather` have a column called `city`. On your `WHERE` clause you filter `city = 'A'`, which table's `city` is it refering to?

You can tell the engine which one you want to filter by preceding the column with it's table name:

```
Select * From cities, weather Where cities.city = 'A'
```

You can also refer to tables with alias:

```
Select * 
From cities AS C, weather AS W 
Where C.city = 'A'
```

But most important, make sure that you **join tables together**, unless you want all records from both tables to be matched without criterion (cartesian product). You can join them with explicit `INNER JOIN`:

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    cities AS C
    INNER JOIN weather AS W ON C.city = W.city
Where 
    C.city = 'A'
```

---

In the example you mention, this query is used:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather, cities
WHERE city = name;
```

But in here, `cities` table has `name` column (instead of `city` which is the one *you* used). So this `WHERE` clause is linking `weather` and `cities` table together, since `city` is `weather` column and `name` is `cities` column and there is no ambiguity because both columns are named different.

Comment: @EzLo I'm sorry you're proposed answer doesn't give correct results:
`"A" "(12,10)" "A" -5 40 "25" "2018-01-10"`
`"A" "(12,10)" "B" 5 45 "15" "2018-02-10"`

Comment: @Zakhar City `B` is being listed because you replaced `name` which is a column with `A` which is a value, thus losing the join between both tables.